# Is this the correct payoff function for mixed strategy matrix games?

Tags: linear-algebra, game-theory

Consider a mixed strategy matrix game where the payoff matrix is (for simplicity)

\begin{bmatrix}
 & a & b\\ 
a & u^1_{aa},u^2_{aa} & u^1_{ab},u^2_{ab}\\ 
b & u^1_{ba},u^2_{ba} & u^1_{bb},u^2_{bb}
\end{bmatrix}

Then we create the matrices $A,B$

where,

$ A = 
\begin{bmatrix}
u^1_{aa} & u^1_{ab}\\ 
u^1_{ba} & u^1_{bb}
\end{bmatrix}$ $\quad B = 
\begin{bmatrix}
u^2_{aa} & u^2_{ab}\\ 
u^2_{ba} & u^2_{bb}
\end{bmatrix}$

Let $x, y$ be the mixed strategy for player 1 and 2 respectively. Is the following the correct payoff function for player 1 and player 2?

---

Player 1 payoff: $x^T Ay$

Player 2 payoff: $y^T B^T x$

---

If so, I have some questions:

- why is $x^TAy$ for player 1? Why is it not $y^TAx$?
- why is there a transpose on $B$ for player 2's payoff?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both are correct. Recall that the payoff is a number so

$$ y^TB^Tx=(y^TB^Tx)^T=x^T(B^T)^T(y^T)^T=x^TBy$$

Personally, I would keep the same notation ($x$ always on the left with $^T$ sign) for both payoffs.